# android paging 3.0 switch two flows for a recyclerview

Tags: android, paging, android-paging, android-paging-3

So, I have two flows that has same response that's coming from two different Api. I have only one recyclerview paging adapter. Now, How do I switch between the two flows when certain conditions are met. for example I have a SearchView if someone types in I have to call an API that will fetch me one response. and if I clear the SearchView I have to return the response from a different api but to the same Recyclerview that is attached.

```
val mySecondList =
        flowOf(
            clearListCh.receiveAsFlow().map { PagingData.empty() },
            Pager (PagingConfig(pageSize = 1)) {
                somePagingSource(aedApi)
            }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

        ).flattenMerge(2)



val searchFlow = mutableSearchData.flatMapLatest {

        IOLog.d(TAG, "search Flow happening..$it")
        val jsonObject = JSONObject()
        jsonObject.put("keyword", it)
        val gson = getGsonObject(jsonObject)

        Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 1, enablePlaceholders = true)) {
            someSearchSource(aedApi, gson)
        }.flow
    }



 private val clearListCh = Channel<Unit>(Channel.CONFLATED)

    private val mutableLIve: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()
    val liveStringData = mutableLIve

    fun clearListChannel() {
        IOLog.d(TAG, "clearListCh called..")
        clearListCh.offer(Unit)
    }
```

In my activity in onCreate I am initializing something like below

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewmodel.searchFlow.collectLatest {
                IOLog.d("mutableSearchData", it.toString())

                adapter?.submitData(it)
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewmodel.mySecondList.collectLatest {

                adapter?.submitData(it)
            }
        }
```

how do I switch between submitData that is sent from one scope to another

Answer (score 0):

In general you want a single stream to collect from so that you can rely on `collectLatest` to cancel the previous generation. In this case you should combine the two Flows together using something like `flattenMerge` as you've done for the first Flow